# MVC reload page after selecting a value from the drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a working solution, but I don't know how to reload the page after a certain ID is selected from the drop down list. My list is being populated from the DB. When I select it, I can see the ID and the corresponding data for it. However, there is no change on the screen.

Controller class:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = test.getStuff();
            ViewBag.IDs = new SelectList(test.getID(), "", "ID");
            return View(model);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getDataBySelectedID(string selectedId)
        {
            var que = test.getHello(selectedId);
            return View(que);

        }
```

View Class:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID", ViewBag.IDs as SelectList) 

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#ID").on("change", function () {
            var selectedId = this.value;
            var url = "/Sample/getDataBySelectedID";

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    selectedId: selectedId
                }
            });
        });
     });
```

How would I be able to reload the page with the selected value and its corresponding data?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in getDataBySelectedID return view similar to Index that is construct model with filter applied and return View(model)

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'. I am getting this error..

Comment: you need to change return type to ActionResult

Comment: That would create another view

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to reload the page after dropdown selection changed, you should handle `change` event to redirect with query string like this:

```
$("#ID").on("change", function () {
   var selectedId = $(this).val();

   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("getDataBySelectedID", "Sample")' + '?selectedId=' + selectedId;
});
```

Take note that `window.location.href` **uses HTTP GET method**, hence the target action  must use `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult getDataBySelectedID(string selectedId)
{
    var que = test.getHello(selectedId);
    // don't forget to repopulate ViewBag from SelectList here

    return View("Index", que); // return same page with different model contents
}
```

Make sure `getHello()` method return type is the same as `getStuff()` method to avoid passed model item related exceptions.

But if you want to submit the form and show it again afterwards, then use `$('form').submit()` instead:

**jQuery**

```
$("#ID").on("change", function () {
   $('form').submit();
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getDataBySelectedID(ViewModel model)
{
    // do something

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use ajax in your case

just do a

```
window.location.href =  "/Sample/getDataBySelectedID?selectedId=" +selectedId;
```

in your onchange function, and in your view return it as

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getDataBySelectedID(string selectedId)
        {
            var que = test.getHello(selectedId);
            return View("~/Index.cshtml",que);

        }
```

hoping "que" is the same kind of model like you are using on your Index function